# Autocomplete attribute behavior difference on Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, iframe, autocomplete

We have a credit card registration page where each input fields are loaded in each individual iframes.

Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/autocomplete-and-iframes-qvy8dz

Using pre-registered test credit cards

- Chrome: All fields are auto-filled
- Safari: Only credit card number field is auto-filled

Is there a way to make Safari behave the same way with Chrome?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Safari's stricter autofill regulations especially about private data like credit card numbers—are probably to blame. Additionally, you might try using JavaScript to trigger it programmatically. This can be achieved by programmatically blurring the form's initial input field after focusing on it. This might aid Safari in identifying the form and completing the forms. Also, make sure you use `name` attribute while working with inputs in HTML.

```
    function triggerAutofill() {
    let firstInput = document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector("input");
    if (firstInput) {
        firstInput.focus();
        firstInput.blur();
    }
   }
```